# C++ executable not working on linux based hosting server

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, centos

I created an static executable for a CGI application in CentOS 64-bit. The program is using cgicc lib. Then I executed the executable on the same machine (where I created executable file) as well as on another CentOS 64-bit machine (where cgicc lib don't exists). On both machines it got executed successfully. But I have a web hosting server there same executable is not working. The web hosting server is linux (64-bit) machine, but not sure of exactly the linux flavor. In log I found internal server error. Even I checked the executable is having 755 permission. Can some one help in finding the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any console output of errors etc?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is maybe your hosting server has different kind of CPUs. Different CPUs have different instruction sets, so different c++ compiler may be used for binaries. Like if you want to run some program on embedded system with ARMs, you need a cross compiler for it.

Comment: May it be the reason of not working that the created binary is on CentOS and hosting server is running on .deb based machine(like Debian or Ubuntu)?

Comment: @vips I would recommend you recompile your code and try, it should be easy to recompile because there is no big difference between Ubuntu and CentOS I think.